# How to safely transfer reference to object across window?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I'm debugging a web application. Javasript in one window create one object and use it as argument to invoke global method in another window. Pseudo code is like below.

```
var obj = new Foo();
anotherWin.bar(obj);
```

In **anotherWin**, the argument is stored in global variable.

```
var g_obj;

function bar(obj)
{
   g_obj = obj;
   ...
}
```

When other function tries to reference **g_obj.Id**, it throws exception "**Cannot evaluate expression**". This happens in IE8.0.7600.16385 on Windows 7.

In Visual Studio debugger, when this exception happens, the **g_obj** shows as

```
 {...}
```

It looks all its properties are lost.

Perhaps the root reason is the object is created in one window but only referenced in another window. The object might be garbage-collected at any time.

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Are these windows within a frameset?

Answer (score 4):

DOM objects do not persist across windows.  However, if you can live with [JSON representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), then I'd **convert your object to JSON**, send it across and then parse the JSON.

**There are several ways to encode and decode JSON in javascript** (hint: using `eval()` is a security disaster).

- Some modern browsers (Firefox >= 3.5, Internet Explorer >= 8.0) provide secure, fast native implementations.
- Some javascript frameworks (e.g. [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/) but [not jquery](http://jquery.com/)) from the same functionality.
- The **most [reliable way](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/)** to do this is **use Douglas Crockford's [`json2.js` library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)**  It is standard's compliant, secure, backwards compatible and will use the browser's native parser if it exists.

Using Crockford's library, your example would become:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
```

[...]

```
var obj = new Foo();
anotherWin.json_bar(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

In *anotherWin*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
```

[...]

```
var g_obj;

function bar(obj)
{
   g_obj = obj;
   [...]
}


function json_bar(json_obj)
{
    bar(JSON.parse(json_obj));
}
```

Don't forget to [minify](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/better-javascript-minification/) `json2.js` - with conservative minification, it is only a 3.5KB hit to your page load size.

Comment: Trivia: Crockford's script doesn't work in Safari 2, because it doesn't implement Object.hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 1):

is this a one-way operation, or do you want changes made in anotherWin to be reflected in the source window?

if it's one way, i'd convert it to a json string, send it over, and  parse it back into an object.

passing a reference may not be doable.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize your object, send it over, then de-serialize it.